# How is swift allowing same method in protocol and protocol extension?

Tags: swift3, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

Here is the map method which seems to be duplicate in Sequence protocol. How is apple doing this? what is the intention behind this?

```
public protocol Sequence {
public func map<T>(_ transform: (Self.Iterator.Element) throws -> T) rethrows -> [T]
}

extension Sequence {
public func map<T>(_ transform: (Self.Iterator.Element) throws -> T)   rethrows -> [T]
}
```

Comment: Have a look at Protocol Extensions in [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html).

Comment: Because that's how protocol extensions work. This is like asking why a football field is 100 yards long: those are the rules of the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The protocol Sequence both *requires* a `map` function and (using a protocol extension) supplies a default *implementation* for it. That is what protocol extensions are *for*.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense.